# read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' in R but successful read in EXCEL

Tags: r, csv

I try to read in a csv file download from [here](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2FStormData.csv.bz2)

I read with the following code

```
storm_data = read.csv('./data/repdata/StormData.csv',sep=",", stringsAsFactors=F)
```

It returns 692288 observations and an error message

```
Warning message:In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
EOF within quoted string
```

And the result is wrong because columns values are mixed with each other.

Then I tried the read.table method

```
storm_data = read.table('./data/repdata/StormData.csv',sep=",", head=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And it returns an error message of

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 547364 did not have 37 elements
```

I pick up the adjacent lines from 547364 and read in a separate text file and it reads OK. So the problem is not really there but somewhere above.

Last, I tried to read it with excel, and it reads just fine (So is my coursera TA with read.csv). It runs OK and got 903871 lines.

I am totally lost on how to debug the script.

Here is my environment information.
My R version is 3.1.1, Rstudio version is 0.98.1028.(32 bit), operating system is win 8.1(64 bit).

PS:I tried all the related method on stack overflow and none works. If I set quote="", lines are wrong. fread won't work because I got \" in the csv file.

Comment: Check the `quote` and the `comment.char` argument of `read.table`. You may have some `"` or `#` in your data.

Comment: You may want to re-download the bzip2 file. `read.csv` of an uncompressed https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2FStormData.csv.bz2 (assuming this is the Coursera data) works fine (slowly, but fine).

Comment: @hrbrmstr 
I did redownload it twice. It gives me the same problem.

Comment: Did you use a browser, `download.file`, command-line `curl`/`wget`? The linked file works fine after uncompressing via `read.csv` here.

Comment: @ nicola. I tried to turn the comment off. Still the same.

Comment: I tried to read your file and I hadn't any error with `read.csv`. However, I got just 902297 rows while `wc -l` gives 1232705. Strange. There must be some multibyte string that messes things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run into the very same error and after hours of searching, I think this will surly do you some benefits.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")
```

Details can be found here:

[coursera](https://class.coursera.org/repdata-036/forum/thread?thread_id=112)

Comment: Link is outdated