# Trying to Read a file. Has special character "SUB" in Notepad++. Crashes my read

Tags: r, file, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

EDIT - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character

That is the character causing my issue. It occurs several times in the file.

Line in my .CSV file is

```
"Bernie+Sanders","3377900000","3377929757",";5:A59 0940;8=","kajdalin","96","155","",0,0,"Thu Dec 31 13:37:36 +0000 2015","RT @realDonaldTrump: ""@deggow: Just heard a 25 year old man say ""I would rather work for Donald Trump than Bernie Sanders""it's time for me &","6.8256e+17","682556208335695872","<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"6.8251e+17","682514849579057152","Thu Dec 31 10:53:15 +0000 2015","Donald J. Trump","realDonaldTrump","New York, NY","5496400","51","<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/android"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for Android</a>"
```

It crashes after reading ;5:A59

Looked into my data. This is from a Twitter user whose username is in Arabic.  That junk, the ";5:A59 0940;8=", is how the API read in the Arabic when I saved it to a file.

In my Notepad++, the CSV shows that junk differently. It shows it with special-invisible characters, which I will show in [brackets].

```
"[DLE];5:A59 [SUB]0940;8="
```

How I am reading the file in :

```
rawData = read.csv("path.csv", header=TRUE,encoding="UTF-8")
```

If it helps, working on Windows 10 in R 3.2.3

How do I avoid this?

To clarify, the .csv has ~80,000 rows. This happens at row ~4908.  Forgive the formatting below, I know things arent lined up perfectly.

```
queryTarget     userID userID_str    userName userScreen_name userFollowers_count userFriends_count userLocation latitude longitude
Bernie+Sanders 3377900000 3377929757 \020;5:A59                                   NA                NA                    NA        NA
 tweetSendTime tweetText tweetID tweetID_str tweetSource replyStatusID replyStatusID_str replyUserID replyUserID_str replyScreenName
NA          NA                        NA                NA          NA              NA                
 retweetedStatusID retweetedStatusID_str retweetedStatus_createdAt retweetedStatus_userName retweetedStatus_screenName
NA                    NA                                                                              
 retweetedStatusLocation retweetedStatusFollowers retweetedStatusFriends retweetedStatusSource
NA                     NA
```

The error I get is :

```
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
EOF within quoted string
```

Comment: Possibly relevant - sounds like a text encoding issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888529/read-csv-warning-eof-within-quoted-string-in-r-but-successful-read-in-excel

Comment: Thanks, tried that about an hour ago though. No luck :(

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874619/reading-in-a-text-file-with-a-sub-1a-control-z-character-in-r-on-windows) Q and A?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried both methods there, the OP and the readr method, and neither provided me with any sort of workable result.